# Connecting two DC voltage sources in series

Tags: dc-motor, adapter, ac-dc

I need a 42 volt DC supply to check a motor.  All I have is one 30V DC source and a few rated lower than this.

Is it possible for me to connect the 30V source and a 12V source in series to get the required voltage?  If yes, what precautions should be taken?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you really want to do so, there are a few things to consider.

- If both power supplies are grounded, you will short out one of the two (trough ground) when you connect them in series.
- You must connect the load only after both supplies are on and working. Likewise, you must disconnect the load before shutting down the power supplies. If you do not do this it is likely that one supply will start or shut down before the other, allowing the still active supply to force current trough the load and the inactive supply.
- You must never overload either of the power supplies, even if they have robust overcurrent, thermal or short circuit protection. If you do, the one that goes into protection mode is likely to be backfed by the other.

An active supply forcing current trough an inactive one is bad because it will cause large currents to flow trough abnormal paths within the power supply circuitry.

You can add some degree of protection by placing reverse biased diodes in parallel with both supplies. The diodes should divert the bulk of the current in the event of backfeeding. It is by no means certain to prevent damage, since the diode voltage drop will still allow a slight negative voltage to affect the power supply output (you can minimize this voltage by using schottky diodes). The diodes must be rated to conduct the full current of the (highest current) power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Lzs3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>