# Isolated DC-DC converter in series

Tags: dc-dc-converter, series

I am still unsure about connecting two DC-DC converters to achieve a higher output voltage. Regarding my [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477721/dcdc-converter-in-series) about [this](https://www.tracopower.com/products/tel3.pdf) DC-DC converter. The answer I selected does not work when no load is connected, and therefore I want to use the answer below but I do not fully understand it.

[image]

Would connecting "Common pin" with Vout+/ Vout- via the load resistors not short the connection I want to make and only produce +15 V/-15 V between my ground?

If this schematic is correct, can I still produce the +15 V/-15 V between the midpoint of the circuit?

EDIT: After the comments I changed my schematic.

[image]

Am I correct, that the COM+ are now the GND connection for my devices that need +15 V?

Comment: i dont understand, isnt this allready dual output (+/-) converter .. so u have +15 / common / -15 ?

Comment: +Vout = +15v 
common = GND
-Vout = -15v
why u need two converters

Comment: Because I need GND-30V and -30V-GND

Comment: no u cant have (+ 30 and +15) of same node if i understand correctly your requirements remember (mid point is GND) its in the drawing

Comment: No, GND is your GND, COM+ and COM- are your +-15V.

Comment: From where to where is the +15V (COM+ to OUT+)?

Comment: @v3xX from one module (+vout is 15V above common) .. (-vout is 15V below common) .. so (+vout to common) is (+15v) .. (+vout to -vout) is (+30v)

Comment: now in your first schematic (u shorted +vout of second chip to -vout of first chip) .. they are on same potential .. which means +vout of first chip is above that point with (+30v) .. and -vout of second chip is below that point with (-30v). so u get +30 / -30 outputs related to (the mid point that you've shorted).

Answer (score 2):

> *The answer I selected does not work when no load is connected*

Those converters don't regulate very well at no load even when used on their own so the above is probably a red-herring: -

[image]

Below 10% load the regulation isn't guaranteed and this is quite common for many DC-DC converters (caveat emptor).

> *Would connecting "Common pin" with Vout+/ Vout- via the load resistors
>   not short the connection I want to make and only produce +15V/-15V
>   between my ground?*

No. The voltages at all the nodes from the bottom to the top are -30, -15, 0 +15 and +30. This assumes you are using a TEL 3-xx23 device.

Comment: These voltages are measured all against GND?

Comment: I edited the labeling on my question. I am correctly interpreting the outputs?

Comment: @v3xX if you are using the TEL 3-xx23 then yes.

Comment: I use 0523. Thank you very much, I will try a testrun in the evening

Comment: @v3xX if this question is answered then you should formally accept one of the answers or, raise a new comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please ensure that GND on "Power Input" (left hand)side and GND on "Power Output" (right hand) side seperated?

Regarding to your schematics they are same Grounds! 
In this case it is not a right way to use Isolated DC-DC converter such like this...
Grounds should be seperated first!
[image: "]

Comment: I can not separate the Grounds. Why cant they share the same reference point?

Comment: Regarding to the datasheet of Tracopower TEL 3-0523 DC-DC converter is an isolated converter.

Comment: İnput and output Side of converter is behaves as physicslly diffetent circuits.

Comment: Imagine that you are using a transformer which has regulated inputs  and outputs. Isolated  DC-DC converter is similar to transformers except it works on DC instead of AC.